# The animation state .. could not be played because it couldn't be found?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to start an animation by pressing a key on my keyboard.

For this I am using the following code:

```
[HideInInspector] public Animation animation;

private void Start()
{
    animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
    {
        animation.Play("AnimationName");
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> The animation state AnimationName could not be played because it
>   couldn't be found!

Although, the animation DOES start, but how can I clear this error?

Comment: Add a screenshot of your animation controller.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZajueyV

Comment: but "AnimationName" isnt the name of it

Comment: I typed AnimationName to keep it kinda classified ^^, but I made sure that the names are exactly the same. Should have told it, my bad.

Answer (score 11):

I think the only possible explaination is that your animation clip is not marked as Legacy.
https://www.unity3dtips.com/zh/the-animation-state-could-not-be-played-because-it-couldnt-be-found/

EDIT with step by step here:

Animations must be marked as legacy to be used with the animation component.

1. In the project window select the animation clips you’re trying to play.
2. Set the inspector to debug mode which exposes hidden variables, in this case it’ll make the “Legacy” checkbox appear.Unity Inspector Debug Mode
3. Tick the “Legacy” checkbox and change the inspector back to normal mode.
   Unity Inspector Animation Clip Legacy Checkbox

   ---

But there is one thing you should know: you should avoid, if possible, the old legacy way to play animation.
Learn how to use an Animator component. Just create an animator, assign your animation clip, decide a boolean for start the animation in the animator component and set it to true in your code (for basic use).
Sure there is some things to do beside code but it will be easier to control your animation, bleand different animations and change them to your needs (it's for example much easier to loop or stop the animation at some point).
It would be also easier to understand when it start and when is playing.

Comment: Yeah I have used the Animator GameObject before as well, but this gave us some trouble with using the transform. This works better with changing the transform at runtime.

Comment: While that link might solve the issue please make sure to reproduce the required steps here as well. Innthe case the URL is down in the future your post becomes useless.

Comment: There is not much info out there about how to use the new animation system for simple animations, it all focuses on boned characters. Thanks for letting us know that the key to get started is an Animator component, as the unity docs don't even say that.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to check is the legacy 'Animation' component on your gameObject that is supposed to perform the animation. In my case things were marked as legacy for the animation on the imported animation but somehow when adjusting settings on my import it dropped the animation it was complaining about from the actual 'Animation' component so once I added it things worked as expected

Inspector in Debug mode showed my animation marked as 'Legacy' true
[image]

My Animation component showed the missing animation
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out, as well as making it impossible to adjust animations in code, the Animator is much slower than the Animation Component.

This could matter, depending on the Platform. From what I can gather, so many users are unhappy with the Animator, that Unity will not depreciate it until they have a better solution.

Therefore, there is no need to stay away from the Animation Component because it is marked 'Legacy'.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34254426)